# Plugging Askbot into existing Django project, Aunthentication and integrating the users

Tags: django, askbot

I installed askbot through pip into my existing local Django project. I merged the askbot settings & Uls files with my existing files. When I go to 127.0.0.1:8000/ its getting redirected to 127.0.0.1:8000/questions. And I can see all my existing users but no sign in is available.
I see a lot of Url redirects not working because of reverse, like `Reverse for 'home' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.` In my backend database all the tables are looking fine. But users are not integrated with askbot, also there is AttributeError with context_processor.py.

1. How to allow my existing and future users, who are authenticated by my existing django project use askbot seamlessly?
2. How does the askbot admin integrates with my existing admin site?
3. Can we convert Jinja2 template to Django tempalte?

This is my template context tuple

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    #askbot
    #'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    #"allauth.context_processors.allauth",
    #"allauth.account.context_processors.account",
    'askbot.context.application_settings',
    #'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'askbot.user_messages.context_processors.user_messages',#must be before auth
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth', #this is required for admin
    'django.core.context_processors.csrf', #necessary for csrf protection
    ###############askbot ended###########
    #"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    #"django.core.context_processors.request",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    "apps.common.utils.context_processors.app_wide_vars",
    "apps.common.context_processors.feedback_questions",
    "allauth.context_processors.allauth",
    "allauth.account.context_processors.account",
    #"allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount",
    #'cms.context_processors.media',
    'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',
    #'admintools_bootstrap.context_processors.site',
)
```